# How can I create a message box from the command line?

Tags: command-line, terminal

How can I create a message box from the command line, either GUI message boxes or message boxes shown inside the terminal?

It would also be interesting to be able to get a simple input back from the user, for example, an input given with radio buttons (yes/no, OK, etc).

Answer (score 179, accepted):

For a standard "box around a message", use `boxes`:

```
echo 'This is a test' | boxes
```

`boxes` will look like this (First one. Second one is a custom like `cowsay`):

[image: Screenshot of an asterix box and an ASCII-art dog holding a sign of text]

---

If you mean an alert box, use `notify-send`:

```
notify-send 'title' 'message'
```

`notify-send` looks like this:

[image: Pop-up message reading "Hello Ashframe..."]

---

You also can use `zenity` for a popup window:

```
zenity --error --text="An error occurred\!" --title="Warning\!"
```

Zenity is more graphical and has more options, like having the window appear as a question, using:

```
zenity --question --text="Do you wish to continue/?"
```

or even progress bars, using:

```
find /usr | zenity --progress --pulsate --auto-close --auto-kill --text="Working..."
```

`zenity` looks like this:

[image: error, question, info, and warning dialog boxes with buttons]

---

Or use `dialog`, for a command-line only message box:

```
dialog --checklist "Choose OS:" 15 40 5 \
1 Linux off \
2 Solaris on \
3 'HP UX' off \
4 AIX off
```

`dialog` looks like this:

[image: dialog TUI with 4 options]

---

Another option is `whiptail`:

```
whiptail --title "Example Dialog" --msgbox "This is an example of a message box. You must hit OK to continue." 8 78
```

`whiptail` looks like this:

[image: whiptail pop-up box with two text buttons]

---

And if you are truly crazy, use `toilet`:

```
toilet -F border -F gay "CRAZY"
```

`toilet` looks like this:

[image: colorful text box reading "CRAZY"]

- [Source for boxes](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/unix-linux-draw-any-kind-of-boxes-around-text-editor.html/unix-linux-boxes-draw-dog-design)
- [Source for dialog 1](http://www.unixcl.com/2009/12/linux-dialog-utility-short-tutorial.html)
- [Source for dialog 2](http://lab46.corning-cc.edu/documentation/shelldialog)
- [Source for zenity 1](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/gui-scripting-with-zenity/)
- [Source for zenity 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035/how-to-show-a-message-box-from-a-bash-script-in-linux)
- [Source for whiptail 1](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail)
- [Source for whiptail 2](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-use-whiptail-to-write-interactive-shell-scripts/)
- [Source for toilet](http://www.mewbies.com/acute_terminal_fun_01_get_ascii-fied_on_the_terminal.htm)

Answer (score 59):

**xmessage**

This is the granddaddy of GUI alerts:

```
xmessage -center "Hello, World!"
```

[image]

Pure retro goodness.

I also bet that it should be widely available on X11 systems.

SO thread: [How to show a GUI message box from a bash script in linux? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035/how-to-show-a-message-box-from-a-bash-script-in-linux)

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: `xmessage` is even installed on Ubuntu Server by default.   So I can use `ssh -Y <host>`  to log into the machine while forwarding x connections and then run `some-command; xmessage "some-command is done"` to pop up a notification on my desktop when the long running command is finished.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes, that is a good tip!

Comment: Cool command. To auto-clear the message after a few seconds: `xmessage -timeout 10 "Goodbye in 10s!"`.

Comment: TINY on a 4k monitor.

Comment: This will do wonders for my long-running rsync commands over ssh.

Comment: Xmessage is a very underestimated little program. You can also use buttons that return different exit status. E.g.: `xmessage -button OK:0,Cancel:101 Hello; echo $?` returns 0 (success) if user presses OK and 101 if he presses cancel.

Comment: On the fonts issue: fonts can be configured. Font size can be changed with `xmessage -fn '-*-*-*-r-*-*-26-*-*-*-*-*-*-*' 'My message'`, use xfontsel for a good tool to find a good font.

Comment: Default xmessage fonts can also be set permanently on .Xresources file on user home, by adding for example `Xmessage*font: -*-*-*-r-*-*-26-*-*-*-*-*-*-*` to the file.

Comment: It would be nice if distributions automatically set nice settings (depending on resolution, fonts and locale) using .Xdefaults or .Xresources to improve readability on all devices.

Comment: Where there is red `||||`  lines at the beginning of the line?

Comment: @alper I think it must have been fashionable in the 80s.

Answer (score 13):

And then just because @polym's completely over the top answer missed the classic messaging:

`write <username> [<terminal>]` - send a message to another user. Either interactively or as part of a pipe with `echo "message" | write username`

[image: write]

---

And the complement to write, `wall` to send a message to all users

[image: wall]

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to pipe the text to a Python wrapper, you can use `terminaltables`:

```
pip3 install colorclass
pip3 install terminaltables
```

Then in the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Robpol86/terminaltables), you can use one of the examples to write a python wrapper.

[image]

Comment: -1 for requiring something as heavy as python, pip and then some packages.

Comment: @einpoklum That's a poor argument, especially since most examples above require the installation of entire new packages and tools, while nearly all people already have python installed.